# Whatsapp open url code opens Boltt Health App instead of whatsapp in ios

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, openurl

I am facing a very funny issue. I have written code to open WhatsApp from my app (as below). I have also handled to show a toast message to the user when whatsapp is not installed in the device. This code works perfectly fine but if the device has Boltt Health App (https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/boltt-health-fitness-anytime/id1244375641?mt=8) installed and does not have Whatsapp, so instead of showing the toast message of "Please install whatsapp from App Store" it opens Boltt Health App

** Note Everything works properly if there is no Boltt App in the device

My code to open whatsapp

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=\(mobileNo)&text=\(msg)"

    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL, options: [ : ],  completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
                }
            } else {
                CommonMethods.showToast(messsage: "Please install whatsapp from App Store", view: view)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a very weird issue, would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying it on a real device or a simulator device?

Comment: I think you are using simulator, try it on really device.

Comment: @OnurTuna I am using a device .. tested on iphone 6s and iphone 7.. PS: Cannot download Whatsapp and Boltt Health on simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted the Info.plist from this app.  For some reason it registers both the `whatsapp` URL scheme and what appears to be a facebook URL scheme:

[image]

I don't know why this app does this, and it probably shouldn't.

I am not sure what you can do about it; URL schemes aren't registered or protected by Apple.  You could try contacting the app developers and ask them why they are registering these URL schemes.  Perhaps it is an error.

I note that the app does include WhatsApp and FaceBook in its `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, so perhaps they accidentally included them in the URL types key and forgot to remove them.

Comment: Ok so that could be the reason why I am getting directed to Bolth Health app.. But how did you get their Info.plist

Comment: I download the IPA from my phone using iMazing